# Excel Auto Fill- is this possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Looking to auto fill a formula  for example : A142:X143, next cell down A143:X144. I am looking for the next formula down to say A144:X145. so in other words instead of 1:2,2:3 I want it to say 1:2,3:4.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula containing cell references like you describe as part of what comes after the `=`, or the result of the formula should be the literal text you've shown?  You have two answers that have interpreted the question in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Excel have the ability to recognize patterns when filling a series.  Enter your formula pattern in 5 or 6 cells, Select those cells, then drag the cell anchor to fill the cells you want to fill.  Make sure you have Fill Series selected.  If Excel recognized the pattern, it will follow your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Pick **any** cell and enter:

```
="A" & 2*ROWS($1:1) +140 & ":X" & 2*ROWS($1:1)+141
```

Then copy down.

[image]